# Syncing multiple GDrive accounts on the same laptop

Tags: google-drive

## My Problem

I have two Google Drive accounts: Work and Personal. I use both extensively on my MacBook Pro.

I can only sign in to a single account on Google's sync app ("Google Drive File Stream", Version: 25.252.289.1612). Therefore, I must upload personal files using the web interface instead of my MBP native directory structure.

## What have I tried

- Google search
- Playing with the sync app

## My Question

Is there a convenient way to sync multiple Google Drive accounts to the same laptop?

Answer (score -1):

It's easy with multiple Mac user accounts.  However, that does mean that you have to switch between accounts when you want to see the other files.  Another option is to segregate the different Google accounts to different browsers.  I use Chrome, Chrome Canary, and Firefox with different Google accounts.